# Converting an Array of Arrays to an Array of Objects Using Built-in d3.js Methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

For d3.js to render charts, it takes input as an array of objects. Here is an example of a typical input:

```
var data = [
    {x: 0, y: 0},
    {x: 1, y: 1},
    {x: 2, y: 4},
    {x: 3, y: 9}
];
```

Assume my data is in the following form:

```
var data = [
    [x, y],
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 4],
    [3, 9]
];
```

Then I need to convert the data from an *array of arrays* into an *array of objects* then feed it to d3.js. **Now I know how to do this. This is a simple problem to solve, and I am not asking about this.**

My question: Is there a built in function in d3.js that converts an *array of arrays* into an *array of objects*? Something similar to built in functions `d3.csv()` or `d3.tsv()`? Why re-invent the wheel if it is already created :)

Thanks.

Comment: didn't really tested but did you tryed "nest.object(array)" https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#nest_object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the implementation in the csv/tsv parser, it looks like [it reads the first row](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/22131977a6a36f08c7cbfcbd7d926838a8177d7f/src/dsv.js#L43) and generates a [converter function](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/master/src/dsv.js#L7-L11) to map the rest of the rows through.

This seems pretty private to the dsv implementation (rather than re-using any utility functions), and doesn't expose anything that can be used on an array rather than text.  So, I'd guess the answer to your question is no.

If you're looking for a super hacky/fragile/bad way of reusing the csv functions, you could always do this*:

```
const result = d3.csvParse(data.map(a => a.join(',')).join('\n'))
```

<sub>*don't do this</sub>